# Why does input with property disabled set to disabled is not submitted?

Tags: html, forms, disabled-input

I have a form where some `input` elements' `disabled` property set to `disabled`. I noticed that with the presence of `disabled=disabled`, they are not submitted on the server. Why does it behave like that?

Comment: By design, as they call it. To have it non editable but still submitted, add `readonly="readonly"` to the input element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that is what `disabled` is [supposed to do](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1). It effectively removes a control from the form while leaving a visible placeholder.

Perhaps you want [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) instead.

Answer (score 3):

When set, the disabled attribute has the following effects on an element:

- Disabled controls do not receive focus.
- Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
- Disabled controls cannot be successful.

  (from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12)

You should use readonly=readonly if you want their values submitted on the server.